# Barcode decoder that generates exact symbols

Tags: barcode

I am trying to decode a barcode and am getting something like `abcdefABCDEFabc...` but I want the exact numbers such as `104 65 66 67 68 69 70 101 33 34 35`

Anyone know a decoder that does this?

Comment: What barcode format is this? Several allow for the full (or mostly-full) range of ASCII characters.

Comment: Its code 128 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128

Comment: Perhaps you are just getting the letter that matches the ASCII code for that number. Try converting it back to numbers.